# TI-84 CSE GDP calculation

Tags: math, ti-basic

I am trying to create a program that will allow me to select a STATLIST (L1,L2,...) as variables and take L1 value one (L1,1) times L2 value 1(L2,1). Then sum that product with all values in the function.

So in a regular function form something like

Sum[(L1,1*L1,1)+(L1,2*L2,2)+(L1,3*L1,3)+...]

This function is to calculate GDP to try and save time during my MacroEcon exam. So if anyone knows a program that will calculate basic economic functions like this given tables that would be even better.

Comment: and the question/problem is? what did you try?

Comment: Sorry, I just simply can not figure out how to make the ti-84 do it. Even without trying to make a program. I've looked in the user manual and everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I'm not entirely sure what you're asking for, but if my understanding is correct, it's not a difficult task.

This is how I understand your question. You need to

1. Accept two lists as input (`L₁` and `L₂`)
2. Multiply every element in `L₁` by the corresponding element in `L₂`
3. Take the sum of the result of step 2

```
:Prompt L₁,L₂
:sum(L₁L₂
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. This is exactly what I needed to know. I apologize for this simple question I was extremely naive about programing. I still have no idea where I would find a list of commands for this type of programing. But thank you.

Comment: @user3846537 The [TI-Basic tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/ti-basic/info) has some links to great resources for TI-Basic programming.

Comment: Sweet, I'll check into it. Thank you again!